# Error response won't show up using vue and blade

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3

I have created a small validation using laravel and vue js but when I tried to display the errors using vue it won't show up inside a div. When I check using dev tools, the messages are there but didn't display to the specified div.

Sample blade:

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errors">
     <ul>
          <li v-for="error in errors">@{{ errors[0]}}</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Sample script:

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: {
            errors: false
        },
        mounted: function() {
            $('.fileinput').fileinput();
        },
        methods: {
            submitForm: function() {
                vm.errors = null;
                var form = document.forms.namedItem("addProjectForm");
                var formdata = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url: $('#addProjectForm').attr('action'),
                    data: formdata,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    method: 'post',
                    error: function(data) {
                        if (data.status === 422) {
                            vm.errors = data.responseJSON;
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        swal("Success", "Project added successfully", "success")
                    }
                }); 
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Just put some logs along your code and debug it.

Comment: @JonatasWalker hey man, I get it now. I just changed the `@{{ errors[0]}}` to `@{{ error[0]}}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is problem :

You are overriding `v-if="errors"` property like this when submit data :

```
this.errors = null
```

This mean your errors are now null not true and not false right.

and because of you added v-if vue looking for errors to be true or false.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errors">
     <ul>
          <li v-for="error in errors">@{{ errors[0]}}</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

You can fix like this :

```
data: {
   errors: false,
   error_messages: null,
},
```

After submit data and check error do this :

```
if (data.status === 422) {
  vm.error_messages = data.responseJSON;
}
```

Then :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errors">
     <ul>
          <li v-for="error in error_messages">@{{ error[0]}}</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

One more thing if you still want to check how it working then use v-show rather then v-if because v-if remove element and v-show will just hide and you can change behaviour by css to `display:block` and there will be your result. but you have to modify if you want to use with v-if;

Comment: Hey.. I just figured it out. I just changed `@{{ errors[0]}}` to `@{{ error[0]}}`. Check my comment below my posted question. But anyway thanks for this.